# Prove that $\left|\cos\left(\frac{(1-2r)\pi}{2n}\right)\right|\leq\left|\cos\frac{\pi}{2n}\right|$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, inequality, circles

Hello everyone I am new here. I am studying engineering and I have taken a Mathematics course as a major. I am interested in studying geometry in future. I was solving a trigonometric problem and stuck after some stages. I need to show the below inequality to complete the original problem. Please help me to solve the inequality:

$$\left|\cos\left(\frac{(1-2r)\pi}{2n}\right)\right|\leq\left|\cos\frac{\pi}{2n}\right|, \quad\mathrm{where} \quad r, n\in \mathbb{N} \quad \mathrm{and} \quad 1\leq r\leq 2n.$$

By drawing graph I can see that the inequality holds correctly but I am unable to solve using mathematical calculation. I shall be really grateful if anyone can help me to solve the inequality. Thank you in advance

Comment: Maybe try using the addition theorem $\cos(a+b) = \cos(a)\cos(b)-\sin(a)\sin(b)$ for the left hand side and then calculate (you can put away with the absolute value by using a case distinction=.

Comment: You probably mean $1\le r\le n.$ You could as well take $r\in\Bbb Z.$

Comment: Thank you for the valuable suggestion @Nuke_Gunray . I had already tried that process but failed miserably. Can you please elaborate a little more? It will be really helpful.

Comment: Thank you for your comment @AnneBauval . I have mentioned in the question that $1\leq r\leq 2n$.

Comment: (I saw, whence my suggestion because at the moment, your $\cos$'s are repeated twice. I suggested either once or an infinity.) The values of your LHS are: $|\cos\frac{(2k+1)\pi}{2n}|$ for $k=0,\dots,n-1.$ Use that $\cos$ is decreasing on $[0,\pi]$ and you will find an upper and lower bound for these $n$ $\cos$'s.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion @AnneBauval . I am trying to solve it using your method.

Comment: Thank you so much once again @AnneBauval . I got the solution as you suggested.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The values of your LHS are: $\left|\frac{\cos(2k+1)π}{2n}\right|$
for $k=0,…,n−1.$
Use that $\cos$
is decreasing on $[0,π]$
and you will find an upper and lower bound for these $n$
$\cos$
's.

Comment: Thank you so much once again @AnneBauval . I got the solution according to your suggestion.